# Optimizing the area of a triangle in space.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization

A triangle has two corners, $(8,0,3)$ and $(0,8,3)$ and a third curve in space that consists of all points $(8,8,a^{2}+3)$, where $a$ is a real number. Calculate the area of the triangle as a function of $a$, $f(a)$ and determine its minimum value.

Comment: Well, I have solved it. No need to worry.

Comment: Then, you maybe want to answer your own question?

Answer (score 1):

Find the length of each of the 3 sides: $\sqrt{8^2+8^2} = 4\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{8^2+a^2}, \sqrt{8^2+a^2}$ and use [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula):

$$
s = 2\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{8^2+a^2}
f(a) = \sqrt{s(s-4\sqrt{2})(s-\sqrt{8^2+a^2})^2}
$$

anf you can minimize $f^2(a)$ for convenience.